# Using multithreading or multiprocessing to display two real-time plots with matplotlib and Tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib, tkinter, multiprocessing

I am making a Python program in which I want to plot the Range-Doppler Map (RDM) of a bistatic radar in a room with a certain number of people moving. I used Tkinter and matplotlib to draw the two plots and a Model-View-Controller structure.

What I would like is that, on the left plot the points move smoothly, and, on the right plot the RDM is displayed every second for example. The problem is that the computation of the RDM takes some time and, as it can be seen on the gif below, the points stop moving during this period. I would like to use multithreading or multiprocessing but I have never used that, and I have some problem with mainloop() of the Tkinter GUI. I tried with the after method of Tkinter but I still have the problem.

[image: GIF of my program]

```
class Controller:
    def __init__(self):

        map_dim = [10, 10]
        points_pos = [[2, 5], [7, 5]]
        points_speed = [3, 0.5]
        points_dir = [math.pi/4, math.pi/2]
        tx_pos = [0, 0]
        rx_pos = [10, 0]

        colors = ['red', 'blue']

        self.view = View()
        self.model = Model()

    def movePoints(self):
        position = self.model.updatePointsPosition(time.time()-self.start_time)
        self.view.updateSimulation(position)
        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.view.after(10, self.movePoints)

    def computeRDM(self):
        x, y, z = self.model.computeParameters()
        self.view.updateRDM(x, y, z)
        self.view.after(1000, self.computeRDM)

    def run(self):
        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.view.after(10, self.movePoints)
        self.view.after(1000, self.computeRDM)
        self.view.mainloop()
```

The structure is the following :

```
model <-> controller -> view(Tkinter.Tk) -> window(Tkinter.Frame) -> canvas(FigureCanvasTkAgg)
```

Comment: Is that real time data, or are you working with stored data?

Comment: I am working with real time data but maybe working with stored data is a better idea !